# Selectivizr working on nth-child(x) but not nth-child(odd/even)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, selectivizr

I'm running Selectivizr and using nth-child(2n+1) for the background color on table rows and it's working fine in IE7 and IE8, but for some reason it's not working for nth-child(odd) where I'm using it for a right margin. Any ideas why?

Unfortunately, I can not provide the page links as they are for a site in production.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are you using with Selectivizr to patch selector support?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. It is part of a conditional statement.
`<!--[if LTE IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sebin/t/i/ie.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="/sebin/j/f/library.ie.js"></script>
 <style> .callout_blocked{overflow:hidden}</style>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: Selectivizr depends on another library to actually patch support for those selectors. What's in library.ie.js?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Got dragged off to another project. Thanks for your help. The contents of library.ie.js can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nf5Zw/